# Send email on click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm a photographer and use my website to share photographs with my clients. I always link them to a password protected directory where they can browse and download the files.

I would like to receive a confirmation email when they have downloaded the photo's.

So when they click on a specific  element I want to send an email to myself. How would I code this?

Comment: what have you tried? there is a mail function in php you can call after user successfully download file.

Comment: take free photos for me and i'll code for free for you.

Comment: You could do an ajax post call to trigger a PHP function that sends an email, so the user won't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a simple ajax request as @Robert suggested - make your php script in a file called `mail.php` or something, similar to below..

```
<?php 

mail("youremail@yourdomain.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);

?>
```

And then on the page that you want the user to download from - detect the click and trigger an ajax call like this..

```
<script>

$('#element').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: { subject: "Someone Downloaded Their Photos", message: "Email Content" }
    });

});

</script>
```

You could replace the subject and message in the jquery to send information about your user in the email, so you know who they are and which photos they are downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple,

Just add a link on the browse page where they can click for download..
and link that page to a php script which will send an email to your email address.
and also will download the image file securely.
cheers :)