# asynchronous email php + jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need to send email asynchronously.

For that I have a jQuery ajax client and PHP backend to actually send eMail, still AJAX's success method is not being called. I understand it is simple, but yet doesn't seem to be working. Can somebody please take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong? Really appreciate it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: {name: "manu", email: "abc@abc.com"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {  
        alert('mail sent');  
        $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg);
    }
});
```

and I have mail.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
echo $name
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

$msg="my email";
$emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission from '.$name;
$sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";
$headers = 'From: Saddi website <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo 1;
?>
```

Comment: What HTTP response code do you get for your AJAX call? Do yo have any errors showing up in web server logs?

Comment: There are already lots of questions on this topic - I answered one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021070/send-email-on-click/17021597#17021597) with a simple example.

Comment: @CalZone Typically you can track all network activity the browser initiates in the "Net" or "Network" panel of your favorite browser-based web developer tools.

Comment: add error:function(msg){console.log(msg)} to your ajax call to see the error

Comment: you set `dataType` json, but don't return `json`. Will cause parse error

Comment: I can also say that, at a very minimum, you won't be able to rely on `$_POST` as you are using `application/json` ContentType header. `$_POST` is not populated in this case.  You will need to read POSTed data from PHP raw input. This is other question I had provided answer to on how to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined/15485690#15485690

Comment: @Wezly Thanks for your link, will probably solve my problem, though its an email, and mine is more of a contact form.

Comment: While that is not part of your question, I strongly recommend you to read some articles about the _dos and don'ts_ of email web-forms. The way you create the subject and headers makes it (if the MTA e.g. supports BCC fields) extremely easy to use your form to submit spam.

Comment: @charlietfl Yup. I think thats what it is. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: @t.niese Yes I understand, but as of now I'm still trying to understand basics about ajax. There is long time before anything goes to production.

Comment: @CalZone I hope so, there are still many web hosting service, that allow the usage of `bcc` headers (mainly to e.g. support a resource saving way for sending newsletters). In that case - with your example  - it would be sufficient to set  `email` to something like this: `\r\nmail1@example.com;mail2@example.com;[some more mail addresses];mail10000@example.com;\r\n` and your form would submit thousands of emails to any foreign address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems.

1. you're echoing just 1, its not JSON. So in your PHP code do `json_encode("msg"=>"1");`
2. In my experience, if you have this

`header("Content-type: application/json");`
OR     `header("Content-type: json/text");`

You won't get any result in jquery `success` or `error` blocks.

```
success: function(msg) {  
    alert(msg);  
}
```

the msg would return null value (or nothing). The alert will happen but will show something like object object.